# How to get all the values bellow the variable that triggers it?

Tags: c++, arduino, mqtt

Hello everyone hope you had wonderful new years eve. I am searching for a command to use in my `IF` function that could read if the values are bellow for the variable that triggered it.

Example of what I am trying to achieve: I have a signal coming trough mqtt back from nodered to my code which is a slider that choses the minimum value(temp) for like turning on a fan. And I need help to get all the values below because when I set the value to say 25 it works only on 25 not below the value. I need this function because the sensor can always jump over my set value from the slider.

So the question is how can I implement a function to `IF` to read the values bellow the variable setting?

As I searched the web I found a command `constrain()` which I don't think I can use because the value can change of the variable when ever, if the slider is moved higher to like 40 or lower to 10

Code for how I doing it right now:

```
if (millis() > millisNow + sendDelay){
  if (TempThres >= 20 && TempThres <= 30 && temp == TempThres) {
    digitalWrite(RELAY_PIN2, HIGH); // turn on led 5 seconds
    delay(5000);
    digitalWrite(RELAY_PIN2, LOW);
  }

  Serial.println ("wwwwwwwwwwwwwww");
  Serial.println(TempThres);
  Serial.println ("wwwwwwwwwwwwwww");

  if (SoilThres >= 1 && SoilThres <= 100 && soilmoisturepercent == SoilThres) {
    digitalWrite(RELAY_PIN15, HIGH); // turn on led 5 seconds
    delay(5000);
    digitalWrite(RELAY_PIN15, LOW);
  }

  Serial.println ("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa");
  Serial.println(SoilThres);
  Serial.println ("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa");
}
```

Comment: Sorry, having trouble understanding your question.  With the code you posted, what's an example of a value or a scenario that would make it misbehave?

Comment: i added the code as a refrence of how would you guys edit this code to solve the problem or have an idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, this will eventually break: `if (millis() > millisNow + sendDelay)`.  I think you want `millis() - lastmillis >= sendDelay`. (example page: https://www.norwegiancreations.com/2018/10/arduino-tutorial-avoiding-the-overflow-issue-when-using-millis-and-micros/)

It looks to me that you do too much testing in your conditions. For temperature, we just want it between 20 and 30 - why do we care if it also happens to match some unknown `TempThres`?  And why would we ever set `TempThresh` outside that range?  Same with the soil moisture.

If those thresholds need to be variable, then construct a low and high limits, and check against those:  `if ( temp >= (thresh - 5) && temp <= (thresh + 5) ) ...`

At least I think that's what you want.

Comment: ```SoilThres``` and ```TempThresh``` is just variables which I am getting back from my nodered(website) so i'm just kinda comparing those to my ```if``` statement if the variable match the selected value on the website the program activates but as I said in the post the ```SoilTheres``` is very inconsistent so i'm afraid of the value droping below the set limit. and the relays wouldn't kick on. Wouldn't the command you wrote just will kick on if the value is exactly 20 or exactly 30 from the original value? or it will have threshold +5 and -5 temp?

Comment: Two separate issues: 1) get data from website and verify/check/range-limit, 2) use the thresholds in the control loop.  The last example I gave above will give you a +/-5 spread around the threshold value.

Comment: Thanks just needed confirmation before accepting the answer :)